# Need to get the values from json based on conditions in Splunk SPL

Tags: amazon-web-services, splunk

I have these three entries in an array and i want to get the cidr_ip of only those entries which have from_port = 22 . in this case that is second entry which has 5 cidr_ips

```
{"grants": [{"owner_id": "376456522198", "cidr_ip": null}, {"owner_id": "376456522198", "cidr_ip": null}], "ipRanges": "", "from_port": null, "to_port": null, "groups": "\n ", "ip_protocol": "-1"}
 {"grants": [{"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "52.59.64.149/32"}, {"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "193.26.194.92/32"}, {"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "182.75.203.18/32"}, {"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "49.207.49.169/32"}, {"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "1.39.182.12/32"}], "ipRanges": "\n ", "from_port": "22", "to_port": "22", "groups": "", "ip_protocol": "tcp"}
 {"grants": [{"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "52.59.64.149/32"}, {"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "182.75.203.18/32"}, {"owner_id": null, "cidr_ip": "193.26.194.92/32"}], "ipRanges": "\n ", "from_port": "3389", "to_port": "3389", "groups": "", "ip_protocol": "tcp"}
```

Comment: Are those 3 separate events, or a single event?

Comment: Hi Simon This is a single event. Actually there are multiple events similar to this. From this single event, i need to extract the port 22 and its associated cidr_ip. It is the data extracted from AWS security groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to use a `rex` command to extract the 3 chunks of JSON that you have in the event. Then I use `mvexpand` to make separate events for each of the possible JSON entries. Using the Splunk `spath` command, I can extract the individual `json` fields. Then it easy to filter for `from_port=22` and then show just the fields we are interested in.

```
| rex max_match=10 "(?<json>{\"grants\":.*?ip_protocol\": \"[^\"]+\"})" 
| mvexpand json 
| spath input=json 
| where from_port=22
| table grants{}.cidr_ip, from_port
```

Please note that the `rex` regular expression relies on the `ip_protocol` to come last in the `json` expression. This may be satisfactory for your needs, or you may be able to modify the regex to work in other cases, depending on what your events look like.